# Showing $f(x)=ax+b$ is a bijection for $a\ne 0$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $a,b\in \mathbb R$ with $a\neq 0$. We shall denote by $f_{a,b}$ the map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$ such that $f(x)=ax+b$ is a bijection.

How can I show that $f_{a,b}$ is a bijection? I understand for something to be bijective it must be injective and surjective, so do I need to show it has those properties instead?

Comment: Yes, show that it is injective and surjective.

Comment: Or you can construct an inverse, i.e. a map $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that $f\circ g=id=g\circ f$. Anyway, the tag looks wrong here, right?

Comment: This is badly stated, "$f$ is a bijection for all $x\in\Bbb R$" doesn't make sense, for a given $x\in\Bbb R$ and $a,b$ fixed, $f_{a,b}(x)$ is a number, not a bijection (the former is an element of the domain set, the latter is a function on the set).

Comment: By the way, it is very strange to say "a bijection for all $x\in\mathbb R$" ... the function *as a whole* is a bijection, it doesn't make sense that it is a bijection relative to individual objects the function works on.

Comment: Hint. I assume you can "solve for $x$ in terms of $y$" in the equation $y= ax+b$. That will pretty much answer your question for you.

Comment: I think this has been [answered](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1230226/how-to-prove-that-gx-axb-is-a-one-to-one-correspondence-where-a-neq0-and) already (A one-to-one correspondence is a bijection).